# C++ error C2027: use of undefined type 'second' (Friend Class)

Tags: c++, class, friend-function

I am learning friend functions (C++) but I can not understand why this code does not work. I get this

> error: "error C2027: use of undefined type 'second'". (line number 6)

It is just an example of course (useless). I am trying to use a member function of another class as friend (just that function). I find some example in the web. But in one old post here someone said that a member function of another class cannot be friend of a class.. Is this true?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class second;

class test
{
    friend void second::fun(test &);
public:
    int j = 89;
private:
    int t = 12;
};

class second
{
public:
    void fun(test &b)
    {
        cout << "Try " << b.j << endl;
    }
    int a = 29;
private:
    int u = 10;
};

int main()
{
    test b;
    second one;
    one.fun(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `second::fun`, a complete definition of `second` is required. You can fix this if you **reverse the order** in which you define these classes and forward-declare `test` instead. But again, `b.j` requires `test` to be defined, so you'll have to **separate and postpone** the definition of `second::fun`:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class test;

class second
{
public:
    void fun(test &b); // test must be declared for using a reference to it
    int a = 29;
private:
    int u = 10;
};

class test
{
    friend void second::fun(test &); // second must be defined to access its member
public:
    int j = 89;
private:
    int t = 12;
};

void second::fun(test &b)
{
    cout << "Try " << b.j << endl;   // test must be defined to access its member
}

int main()
{
    test b;
    second one;
    one.fun(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes.. In fact. So here the only one solution is to separate the classes in more files?

Comment: Or you can have it as I posted it.

Comment: If class second is actually declared in a header file, then either you need to put second::fun in second.cpp, or you will need to leave second::fun in the header file - but it will need to be declared inline.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class test;

class second
{
public:
    void fun(test &b);
    int a = 29;
private:
    int u = 10;
};

class test
{
    friend void second::fun(test &);
public:
    int j = 89;
private:
    int t = 12;
};

void second::fun(test &b)
{
    cout << "Try " << b.j << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues with you code.  For

```
friend void second::fun(test &);
```

To work the compiler must know what `second` is.  Since it is an incomplete type you will get a compiler error.  In order to fix that you need declare `second` before test.  Doing that brings up another issue as

```
second::fun(test &b)
```

uses `test`.  To fix this we would forward declare `test` and then declare `second`.  After changing that you need to move the actual function definition out of `second` and have it after `test`.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class test;
class second
{
public:
    void fun(test &b);
    int a = 29;
private:
    int u = 10;
};
class test
{
    friend void second::fun(test &);
public:
    int j = 89;
private:
    int t = 12;
};

void second::fun(test &b)
{
    cout << "Try " << b.j << endl;
}

int main()
{
    test b;
    second one;
    one.fun(b);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/860d208d57fd5403)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler reads this line

```
friend void second::fun(test &);
```

it does not know whether the class second indeed has data member `fun`. To be sure that this line is correct the compiler needs the definition of the class `second`.

On the other hand, the definition of the function `fun` must know that class `test` has data member `j`.

To resolve the collision you can write the following way

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test;

class second
{
public:
    void fun(test &b); // class test is already declared above
    int a = 29;
private:
    int u = 10;
};

class test
{
    friend void second::fun(test &); //class second is already defined above
public:
    int j = 89;
private:
    int t = 12;
};

void second::fun(test &b)
{
    cout << "Try " << b.j << endl; // class test is already defined above
}

int main()
{
    test b;
    second one;
    one.fun(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried but these are the errors in this case: Error 1 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'test', Error 2 error C2245: non-existent member function 'second::fun' specified as friend (member function signature does not match any overload) , Error 3 error C2511: 'void second::fun(test &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'second', Error 4 error C2660: 'second::fun' : function does not take 1 arguments

Comment: @user5507798 See my updated code. You need to declare the class test before the class second